# Confusion with literals, arithmetic in C

Tags: c, literals

I wrote the following code with an expectation that it output `211`, but when I compile and run it, I see `137`.

Could someone please explain what's going on?  Thanks.

```
‎#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int binary1,binary2;

    binary1 = 0100;
    binary2 = 0111;

    printf("%d\n", binary1 + binary2);

    return 0:
}
```

Comment: Even if those _were_ binary numbers, you'd get `8 + 11 = 19`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are not binary numbers but [*octal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (base 8):

```
binary1 = 0100; // = 64
binary2 = 0111; // = 64 + 8 + 1 = 73

printf("%d \n", binary1 + binary2); // = 64 + 73 = 137
```

Answer (score 6):

Because `%d` prints out the numbers in decimal. If you want to print octal numbers, you would need to use `%o`, which would print out **211**.

- `%d`: decimal => 137
- `%o`: octal => 211

`printf()` does not know you defined the numbers in octal.

Answer (score 3):

The leading zeroes in 0100 and 0111 means the numbers are to be interpreted as octal numbers. 100 in octal is 64 in decimal and 111 in octal is 73 in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Both numbers are in octal, and add them in base 8.

Answer (score 1):

In C a numeric literal prefixed with a '0' is octal (base 8). That why it is displaying the result 137

0100 in octal is equivalent to 64 in decimal and 0111 is to 73,

```
so 64+73 = 137
```